# Org-mode: Sparse tree matching uncheduled, undone headlines without children

Tags: emacs, org-mode, emacs24

In an org file, I want to find undone headlines that are not scheduled, and have no undone children that are scheduled either.

That is, headlines like the following:

```
* TODO Parent
* TODO Parent
** DONE Child 1
** DONE Child 2
```

But not like the following:

```
* TODO Parent
** TODO Child 1
*** TODO Child 1.1
    SCHEDULED: <2016-08-22>
```

I'd like to limit that search to headlines in a specific TODO state (that is, if they are marked as "WAITING", then it's fine to be unscheduled).

Is it possible to do so, ideally with a sparse tree in the text buffer? (I specifically want to avoid the agenda for this.)